# I have a class which holds attributes for a menu item. I need to populate three JLists. How can I do so?

Tags: java, swing, class, jframe, jlist

The attributes in the `MenuItem` class for the menu item's include name, price, calories and description. The three `JList` components are called `startersList`, `mainsList` and `dessertsList`, and are in a `JFrame` called `foodOptionGUI`

At the moment I have populated the lists through using:

```
startersList.setListData(starters);
```

(This is only a temporary fix)

My problem is I'm not sure how to list all the starters, mains and desserts including their name, price, calories and description, into the three separate lists.

```
public class MenuItem {

    private String name;
    private String price;
    private String descriptions;
    private int calories;

    public MenuItem(String Name, String Price, String desc, int cal) {

        name = Name;
        price = Price;
        descriptions = desc;
        calories = cal;
    }

    public String getPrice(){
        return price;
    }


    public String getName(){
        return name;    
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescriptions(){
        return descriptions;
    }

    public void setDescriptions(String desc){
        this.descriptions = desc;
    }

    public int getCalories(){
        return calories;
    }

    public void setCalories(int cal){
        this.calories = cal;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name + ", " + price + ", " + calories + ", " +     descriptions ;
    }

}
```

Comment: `private String price;` should probably be `private int price;` (listing a price in cents, pence or parts of a Euro). The `MenuItem` might also declare 3 constants to delineate between starters, mains and deserts. e.g. `public static final int STARTER = 0;` and have the user of the class (the programmer) define the appropriate category for the item when it is constructed. *"My problem is I'm not sure how to list all the starters, mains and desserts including their name, price, calories and description, into the three separate lists."* What is the problem, exactly? Surely you are putting the ..

Comment: .. `MenuItem` objects into the list, the list then just needs to be configured to display what the end user needs to see. Personally I'd make the info. in the list 'minimal' and show the other details on mouse over of selection (in other fields). So ..what is the problem, specifically?

Comment: Sorry i was a bit unclear there. What I meant to say i don't know how to create the objects, I have tried:                                                                                    startersList = new JList();
  startersList.setBounds(30, 87, 122, 137);
  contentPane.add(startersList);
  startersList.addMenuItem("soup", "3", "300", "soup of the day");  But its wrong and doesnt work

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Make sure to only include **one list** and remove all the other unnecessary stuff.

Comment: @SJ21W, So you have asked two questions in this forum. Why have you not yet responded to any of the suggestions indicating whether they helped or not?

Answer (score 1):

```
startersList.addMenuItem("soup", "3", "300", "soup of the day");
```

> But its wrong and doesnt work

Well a `JList` doesn't have an "addMenuItem" method.

You add data to the `ListModel`. Then you add the `ListModel` to the `JList`.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) for demo code you can download.

In the demo code `String` data is added to the `ListModel`. In your case you want to add a `MenuItem` object to the model, so you first need to create an instance of each `MenuItem` object before you add it to the model.

So the basic difference in the code from the tutorial and your code will be:

```
listModel = new DefaultListModel();
listModel.addElement( new MenuItem(values for item 1) );
listModel.addElement( new MenuItem(values for item 2) );
list = new JList(listModel);
```