# Displaying a variable from an ArrayList of objects in a JScrollPane

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

one with a static ArrayList and one with a UI that is set up, I am wanting to show a list of each of the objects foodName because this is going to be food items that can be selected and ordered on an online menu GUI.

```
    public class MenuItem
    {  
        private String foodName;
        private String foodType;
        private float price;
        private int calories;    

        /**
         * Constructor for objects of class MenuItem
         */
        public MenuItem(String nameFood, String typeFood, float foodPrice, int caloryCount)

        {     
        foodName = nameFood;
        foodType = typeFood;
        price = foodPrice;
        calories = caloryCount;

       } 

       public String foodName()   
       {
         return foodName;       
       }

       public String foodType()   
       {
          return foodType; 
       }

       public float price()
       {
           return price;
       }

       public int  calories()
       {
           return calories;
        }
    }
```

This above is my class for each MenuItem.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * 
 * ArrayList for the class, will hold all food items
 * @author Jonathan
 * @version 1.0
 *
 */

public class RestaurantArrayList extends MenuItem
{


    public RestaurantArrayList(String nameFood, String typeFood, float foodPrice, int caloryCount) {
        super(nameFood, typeFood, foodPrice, caloryCount);

    }

    public static final ArrayList<MenuItem> items;

    static 
    {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new MenuItem("Coca Cola", "Drink", 3.00f, 38));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Fanta Orange", "Drink", 3.00f, 31 ));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Glass of Red Wine", "Drink", 5.00f, 85));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Glass of White Wine", "Drink", 5.00f, 82));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Carling", "Drink", 3.50f, 189));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Fosters", "Drink", 3.50f, 378));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Water", "Drink", 0.00f, 0));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Breads", "Starter", 5.00f, 150));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Cold Meat", "Starter", 5.00f, 150));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Potato Skins and Barbeque Sauce", "Starter", 5.00f, 500));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Cold Meat", "Starter", 5.00f, 400));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Garlic Bread and Cheese", "Starter", 4.50f, 450));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Steak", "Main", 13.50f, 750));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Cheese and Bacon Burger", "Main", 8.00f, 850));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Spaghetti Cabonara", "Main", 7.00f, 675));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Steak", "Main", 13.50f, 378));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Seafood Paella", "Main", 10.00f, 850));
    }
}
```

Here is the ArrayList Class I have also set up. I am wanting to just display the name of the food in the text area but I am not sure how to do this. If anyone can help that would be great. Thanks

```
JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane_1.setBounds(219, 50, 134, 309);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane_1);
```

this is a little snippet of code setting up a JScrollPane as well that I am wanting the information to be displayed inside, which is within its own GUI class.

Comment: I wish you guys would talk to one another in class before posting on the forums. See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36385911/i-have-a-class-which-holds-attributes-for-a-menu-item-i-need-to-populate-three

Comment: @camickr: indeed! 1+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a [JList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html) with a custom [DefaultListCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListCellRenderer.html). Cell renderers determine how the objects in a cell is shown, so in your case you want `MenuItem` objects in your `JList` and the renderer should extract the name string for showing. Here's what I drafted:

Create a JList and add it to the viewport of a JScrollPane:

```
JList foodList = new JList(RestaurantArrayList.items.toArray());
foodList.setCellRenderer(new FoodListRenderer());
JScrollPane scr = new JScrollPane(foodList);
```

and custom ListCellRenderer class:

```
class FoodListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    String name = ((MenuItem) value).foodName();
    return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, name, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to display a list of items is not to use a JTextArea but rather either a JList if you're just displaying a single column of information (such as the menu item's name) or a JTable if you want to display a table of data with multiple columns.

Steps for the simple, way, the JList:

- Create a `DefaultListModel<MenuItem>` object
- Fill it with MenuItem's using its `addItem(...)` method, just as you fill your ArrayList above.
- Place it into a `JList<MenuItem>`
- Place the JList into a JScrollPane.
- Set your JList's visible row count by calling `setVisibleRowCount(...)` on it.
- Make sure that the JList displays the item correctly by either

  - giving MenuItem a `public String toString()` method that returns the MenuItem's name, or
  - giving your JList a renderer that displays the MenuItem's name.

For more on JList -- please check out the [Swing JList Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html).

If you want to increase the power of your display, then a JTable is the route to go, but this will mean an increase in the complexity of your code since you'll need to create your own TableModel, by either extending DefaultTableModel (simpler but limited) or AbstractTableModel (harder to do, but with greater flexibility and power). If you are interested in this route, please have a look at the [Swing JTable Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

---

Side recommendations (unrelated to your original problem):

- This, `scrollPane_1.setBounds(219, 50, 134, 309);` suggests that you're using `null` layouts, and if so, you'll want to change out of this habit. While null layouts and `setBounds()` might seem to Swing newbies like the easiest and best way to create complex GUI's, the more Swing GUI'S you create the more serious difficulties you will run into when using them. They won't resize your components when the GUI resizes, they are a royal witch to enhance or maintain, they fail completely when placed in scrollpanes, they look gawd-awful when viewed on all platforms or screen resolutions that are different from the original one.
- Avoid over-use of static. When you use static fields, such as your ArrayList above, you throw that field out of the object-oriented realm and into the static realm. If done with care and only when absolutely needed, this is OK, but it should be avoided if possible since this risks increasing program complexity (cyclomatic complexity to be precise) and thus the risk of bugs.