# Showing Items of Set Types from an ArrayList in a JList

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, arraylist, actionlistener

I have setup a GUI for a restaurant where it will show items from an ArrayList in a JList, so it won't show all items I have it so when you click on say a Mains button it will show main courses, when click on dessert it will show dessert etc. I tried to implement that in the main course action listener but it is still showing all items.

```
// sets up the class MenuItem, this can then be used to generate different types of food and put them
//into catagories like starter, main course etc
//@Jonathan Gedlek
//@Version 1.0 31/03/16


public class MenuItem
{  
    public static String typeFood;
    private String foodName;
    private String foodType;
    private float price;
    private int calories;    

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class MenuItem
     */
    public MenuItem(String nameFood, String typeFood, float foodPrice, int caloryCount)

    {     
    foodName = nameFood;
    foodType = typeFood;
    price = foodPrice;
    calories = caloryCount;

   } 

   public String foodName()   
   {
     return foodName;       
   }

   public String foodType()   
   {
      return foodType; 
   }

   public float price()
   {
       return price;
   }

   public int  calories()
   {
       return calories;
    }


}
```

Here is my Menu Item class so it is setting up the objects to be added into an ArrayList.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * 
 * ArrayList for the class, will hold all food items
 * @author Jonathan
 * @version 1.0
 *
 */

public class RestaurantArrayList extends MenuItem
{


    public RestaurantArrayList(String nameFood, String typeFood, float foodPrice, int caloryCount) {
        super(nameFood, typeFood, foodPrice, caloryCount);


    }


    public static final ArrayList<MenuItem> items;

    static 
    {
        items = new ArrayList<>();
        items.add(new MenuItem("Coca Cola", "Drink", 3.00f, 38));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Fanta Orange", "Drink", 3.00f, 31 ));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Glass of Red Wine", "Drink", 5.00f, 85));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Glass of White Wine", "Drink", 5.00f, 82));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Carling", "Drink", 3.50f, 189));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Fosters", "Drink", 3.50f, 378));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Water", "Drink", 0.00f, 0));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Breads", "Starter", 5.00f, 150));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Cold Meat", "Starter", 5.00f, 150));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Potato Skins and Barbeque Sauce", "Starter", 5.00f, 500));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Cold Meat", "Starter", 5.00f, 400));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Garlic Bread and Cheese", "Starter", 4.50f, 450));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Steak", "Main", 13.50f, 750));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Cheese and Bacon Burger", "Main", 8.00f, 850));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Spaghetti Cabonara", "Main", 7.00f, 675));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Steak", "Main", 13.50f, 378));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Seafood Paella", "Main", 10.00f, 850));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Chocolate Gateau with Cream", "Dessert", 5.00f, 179));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Apple Pie and Cream", "Dessert", 5.00f, 237));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Lemon Cheese Cake", "Dessert", 5.00f, 250));
        items.add(new MenuItem("Strawberries and Cream", "Dessert", 3.00f, 200));


    }

    public static String getFoodName(int index)
    {
        return items.get(index).foodName();
    }

    public static String getFoodType(int index)
    {
        return items.get(index).foodType();

    }

    public static int getCalories(int index)
    {
        return items.get(index).calories();
    }

    public static float getPrice(int index)
    {
        return items.get(index).price();
    }

    public static int getListSize()
    {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

This is my ArrayList class, I am trying to get it to show only items in the list which has foodType set as Main.

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.JList;

class FoodListRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

/**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
    String name = ((MenuItem) value).foodName();
    return super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, name, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
}}
```

This is my FoodListRenderer class

```
JButton btnMainMenu = new JButton("Main Menu");
btnMainMenu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

        for (int i = 0; i<RestaurantArrayList.getListSize();i++)
        {
            if(RestaurantArrayList.getFoodType(i) == "Main")
            {
                JList foodList = new JList(RestaurantArrayList.items.toArray());
                foodList.setCellRenderer(new FoodListRenderer());
                scrollPane_1.setViewportView(foodList);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }

    }
});
```

Lastly this is my button that I will press to show just Main course items.
There isn't anything syntactically wrong but still won't work the way I am intending it too. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `Any help will be appreciated` - really? You didn't appreciate any of the help received here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36429167/displaying-a-variable-from-an-arraylist-of-objects-in-a-jscrollpane or here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36570257/moving-objects-from-one-arraylist-to-another-with-swing/36576797#36576797. You haven't "accepted" any of the answers or thanked anybody for the time spent helping you. So I think I'll skip this one.

Comment: `RestaurantArrayList.getFoodType(i) == "Main"` will fail as you do not compare strings this way. Use `RastaurantArrayList.getFoodType(i).equalsIgnoreCase("Main");`

Comment: I do appreciate the help I received in my first question and I thought I had ticket it and responded to the person for his help but the last question I didn't get a straight answer and me and a friend worked it out ourselves. I'm sorry if it appeared as pretentious but I really didn't mean too and I just want some help.

Comment: `I thought I had ticket it and responded to the person` - and yet it still haven't been accepted. `I didn't get a straight answer` - an answer doesn't mean we write the code for you. It means we provide you with the information necessary to solve the problem. You were given plenty of information needed to solve the problem including a link to a working example. `and a friend worked it out ourselves.` - so did you post the answer and close the question so other people don't spend time reading and answering the question?

Comment: You are still using static variables and methods all over the place even though you have been told it is a terrible design. You are still using the ArrayList even though you were told you should be using a ListModel. Why should we help when you ignore the suggests. Did you ever think your incorrect solutions are causing all the problems? That is another reason you were given a link to the tutorial. The demo code shows you how to better structure your class to get rid of all the static code.

Comment: I see that you use this a lot but I have only ever used this to ask three questions, I am still getting used to it I'm sorry I did something wrong, and I went to tick what was correct on the first answer but  I can already see a tick so I can't really do much about that, I will close the previous question.

Comment: The simple answer is to create 3 ListModels. One each to contain the items for starters, entrees and desserts. Then you can just change the model of the JList by using the `setModel(...)` method.

Comment: alright, thank you I will change it to have list models instead of ArrayLists.